# Doctrine (Symfony3) Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to (bundle) must be an instance of (bundle), array given

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a problem in symfony or doctrine.
I have an entity `notificationsettinggroupdetail` and `notificationsettinggroup`.

`Notificationsettinggroup` and `notificationsettinggroup` is master detail and have a join condition in entity doctrine.

The problem comes to me when I want to remove data detail from master (`notificationsetinggroup`) using:

```
    /**
 * Remove notificationSettingGroupDetail
 *
 * @param \Dsp\DspAdministrationBundle\Entity\notificationSettingGroupDetail $notificationSettingGroupDetail
 */
public function removeNotificationSettingGroupDetail(notificationSettingGroupDetail $notificationSettingGroupDetail)
{
    $this->NotificationSettingGroupDetail->removeElement($notificationSettingGroupDetail);
}
```

but when i use this, i got some error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Dsp\DspAdministrationBundle\Entity\notificationSettingGroup::removeNotificationSettingGroupDetail() must be an instance of Dsp\DspAdministrationBundle\Entity\notificationSettingGroupDetail, array given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony-DspWebApp\src\Dsp\DspAdministrationBundle\Controller\Api\ApiNotificationSettingGroupController.php on line 122 and defined
```

this is code in controller:

```
$entityDetailDelete = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(notificationSettingGroupDetail::class)->findNotificationGroupSettingDetailByMaster($userOld[$i]['id']);
$entity->removeNotificationSettingGroupDetail($entityDetailDelete);
```

where is my fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an array not the entity, if you don't want to edit the controller try this:

```
public function removeNotificationSettingGroupDetail(array $notificationSettingGroupDetails)
{
    foreach (notificationSettingGroupDetails as notificationSettingGroupDetail) {
        $this->NotificationSettingGroupDetail->removeElement($notificationSettingGroupDetail);
    }
}
```

Instead if you want to change the controller try this (if is implemented):

```
findOneNotificationGroupSettingDetailByMaster
```

instead of this:

```
findNotificationGroupSettingDetailByMaster
```

because `findNotificationGroupSettingDetailByMaster` returns an array not a single entity